# insert bulk xml data into single table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, xmltable, oracle-xml-db

I was trying to do an INSERT INTO  .. SELECT from xmltable. The procedure completes successfully(quickly) without this insert, but when this code is included to insert 9999 rows it takes its time to complete but the table does not have any records.

FILE SNIPPET:

```
<xyzcompany xmlns="http://www.xyzcompany.com/Canonical" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pmt="http://xyzcompany.com/PmtInfo" xmlns:cmn="http://xyzcompany.com/CommonTypes">
<Pmt>
<pmt:Payments>
<pmt:PayInfo>
<pmt:Single>
<pmt:SingExtRef>HH00000066530</pmt:SingExtRef>
<pmt:SingSequence>0001</pmt:SingSequence>
<pmt:SingAddInfo>
   <cmn:AddInfoCmpType>IndivID</cmn:AddInfoCmpType>
   <cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
   <cmn:AddInfoCmpText>30UAT23203</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
</pmt:SingAddInfo>
<pmt:SingAddInfo>
  <cmn:AddInfoCmpType>Transaction Reference</cmn:AddInfoCmpType>
  <cmn:AddInfoCmpText>062001180000553</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
</pmt:SingAddInfo>
<pmt:SingAddInfo>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpType>EntryDesc</cmn:AddInfoCmpType>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>TRADE PYMT</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
</pmt:SingAddInfo>
<pmt:SingAddInfo>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpType>ACH Company ID</cmn:AddInfoCmpType>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>1444444444</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
</pmt:SingAddInfo>
<pmt:SingAddInfo>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpType>PmtRelInfo0001</cmn:AddInfoCmpType>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>IV</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>UAT9999_00001</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>100.01</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
</pmt:SingAddInfo>
<pmt:SingAddInfo>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpType>PmtRelInfo0002</cmn:AddInfoCmpType>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>IV</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>UAT9999_00002</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>100.01</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
<cmn:AddInfoCmpText>NA</cmn:AddInfoCmpText>
</pmt:SingAddInfo>
</pmt:Single>
</pmt:PayInfo>
</pmt:Payments>
</Pmt>
</xyzcompany>
```

The above file has PMTRELINFO001 up to a max of PMTRELINFO9999. I only need to grab these and not the other data such as INDIVID and insert into the destination table. My code for that is below.

```
INSERT INTO ach_addenda(ach_id,rmr_number,rmr_code,invoice_number,rmr_paid_amt,rmr_orig_amt,rmr_disc_amt,rmr_date,ref_code,ref_id,ref_name,ref_instructions,adx_instructions,
        ent_number)
        (SELECT app_data_seq.currval, 

                 sing_d1.sing_info_type,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text1,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text2,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text3,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text4,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text5,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text6,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text7,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text8,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text9,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text10,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text11,
                 sing_d1.sing_info_text12


            FROM XMLTABLE (
                    xmlnamespaces (
                       'http://www.xyzcompany.com/Canonical' AS "xyz",
                       'http://xyzcompany.com/PmtInfo' AS "pmt",
                       'http://xyzcompany.com/CommonTypes' AS "cmn",
                       'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi"),
                    '/xyz:xyz/xyz:Pmt/pmt:Payments/pmt:PayInfo/pmt:Single/pmt:SingAddInfo[cmn:AddInfoCmpType = "PMTREL%"]'
                    PASSING payXml
                    COLUMNS sing_info_type VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpType',
                            sing_info_text1 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[1]',
                            sing_info_text2 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[2]',
                            sing_info_text3 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[3]',
                            sing_info_text4 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[4]',
                            sing_info_text5 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[5]',
                            sing_info_text6 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[6]',
                            sing_info_text7 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[7]',
                            sing_info_text8 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[8]',
                            sing_info_text9 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[9]',
                            sing_info_text10 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[10]',
                            sing_info_text11 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[11]',
                            sing_info_text12 VARCHAR2(4000)
                                  PATH 'cmn:AddInfoCmpText[12]'
                            ) sing_d1
                            );
```

Any suggestions to increase efficiency and make the insert work is appreciated. I have also tried the insert with the append hint, no difference.

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: "it takes its time to complete."  What does that mean?  Hours, weeks, years?  Did you do a commit?  You mention, "procedure."  is this in a pl/sql procedure?

Comment: No commit. It takes around 15 minutes to complete the procedure, gets stuck on the insert statement, but no records are inserted, no error generated on execution. Minus the block of code, takes 30 seconds.

Comment: So if you just run the "select" part of the above SQL, it returns data?  What do you mean, "gets stuck?"  If there is no commit somewhere, why are you expecting data in the table?  I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 mistakes in your query.

```
   XMLTABLE (
                    xmlnamespaces (
                       default 'http://www.xyzcompany.com/Canonical',
                       'http://xyzcompany.com/PmtInfo' AS "pmt",
                       'http://xyzcompany.com/CommonTypes' AS "cmn",
                       'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi"),
                    '/xyzcompany/Pmt/pmt:Payments/pmt:PayInfo/pmt:Single/pmt:SingAddInfo[contains(upper-case(cmn:AddInfoCmpType),"PMTREL")]'
                    PASSING a ).
```

1) Root nood is `xyzcompany` not `xyz`

2) `http://www.xyzcompany.com/Canonical` is default namespace and should be decorated in that way `default 'http://www.xyzcompany.com/Canonical',`

3) `cmn:AddInfoCmpType = "PMTREL%"` In xquery there is not like operator. It can be replaced with  `pmt:SingAddInfo[contains(upper-case(cmn:AddInfoCmpType),"PMTREL")]`

Comment: Thank you for amending the clause. The performance part of the issue is still valid, it has been running for close to 20 minutes on the insert of 9999 rows. Any ideas? Should i use hints?

Comment: try with `NO_MERGE` without any argument in select, and `parallel` in insert

Comment: INSERT /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ INTO .. SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ ... is not helping. I have all the constraints disabled to let this direct load.